# Coded UI Test Result File

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I use coded UI to run test and get the test result file named like qian_machinename 2011-12-21 14_26_10. I want to read the file and send a test report. My question is how can I get the file time every time I run the tests?

Comment: could you be more explanatory about your steps of doing it. I mean, how your generating the test file. why cant you store the time pick as a file name for file to another code where it can pick the file and generate report. 

Kindly provide more clear infor. Thanks

Comment: You want the file as soon as it is created?

Comment: @zenwalker 
Sorry for unclearness. My code structure is like this:
[Test Mothod]
public void test()
{...}
Then a method call the test method. And the test automatically runs then the test result file created automatically by VS2010. I just want a way to get the generated file name or if I can rename the file, it'll be great.

Comment: @P.K Yes, since the file is generated by VS2010. I need the infomatino in the file to generate a simple test report. Is there any API can get the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestContext has 3 properties which you can use
1. TestDir
2. TestDeploymentDir
3. TestResultsDirectory.

You can use these properties to navigate to the folder you are interested in and then get the result file for your processing.

Comment: Thanks, these properties do have the info I need. But I tried and find other questions, I cannot use these properties outside the [Test Mothod] and the error message is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."My code is like this:
public class Test
{
   public string resultFile = null;
   [Test Method]
   public void T1()
   {
      int i = 1;
      Asser.AreEqual(i,1);
      resultFile = TestContext.TestResultsDirecroty;
   }
}

Can you help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

QianLi,

Perhaps you can get the proper output file by using a known pre-fix on the test output filename.

In Visual Studio navigate Test->Edit Test Settings->(Select your active .testsettings)->General

In the prompt that displays you will see an area for naming scheme.  By default this is set to name your output file "USER@MACHINE DATE TIME".  You can create a user defined scheme and use that to locate the file i.e. store "MyTestOuput" as a pre-fix and then later in code you can examine the file creation date/time if necessary to verify you have the correct output.

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio 2010 TestSettings]

Answer (score 1):

Use something Like :
 FileName=
**testContext.ResultsDirectory + "\" + testContext.TestName.ToString()+".extension"**

1. Testname should be the name of the testMethod Like "T1".
2. Extension could be any valid file type e.g. .xml etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestCleanup()]
    public void MyTestCleanup()
    {
        string nomfichiersource = "UITestActionLog.html";
        string nomTest = TestContext.TestName.ToString();
        string sourcefile = System.IO.Path.Combine(TestContext.TestResultsDirectory, nomfichiersource);
        string destfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"X:\Temp", nomTest + ".html");
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourcefile, destfile);
    }
```